# Global variables in button click function are undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas on which I place `textObjects` (array of Text()) which are drawn on the canvas. I'm able to move these objects individually and upon selection (and in debug I can see that) the object is saved in a global variable called `mySel`.

My problem is that once I click the button (#btn-bold) my globale variables `textObjects` and `mySel` are both undefined. On button click I want to loop through my list of `textObjects` and edit the fontStyle of the textObject with the same position as `mySel`.

Why does this happen and how can I fix this. I call and set the global variables in other functions but when I call for the click function they are undefined.

*Add Text is called from a JQuery modal dialog button. The Canvas is refreshed every 20ms using the function `setInterval(draw, 20)` in the init()*

*I provided the code that's responsible for adding to the list, drawing the list and mouse movement. If the initialize and/or initialization of variables are needed I'll post them.*

**Javascript**

```
function Text() {
    this.text = "Hallo";
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.fillColor = "black";
    this.fontFamily = "Arial";
    this.fontStyle = "normal";
    this.fontSize = "18pt";
    this.fontWeight = "normal";
}

function addText(text, fillColor, fontSize, fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, x, y) {
    var textTemp = new Text;
    textTemp.text = text;
    textTemp.fillColor = fillColor;
    textTemp.fontSize = fontSize;
    textTemp.fontFamily = fontFamily;
    textTemp.fontWeight = fontWeight;
    textTemp.fontStyle = fontStyle;
    textTemp.x = x;
    textTemp.y = y;

    textObjects.push(textTemp);
    invalidate();
}
var textObjects = [];
var mySel;
function drawText(context, textObject) {
    if (textObject.x > WIDTH || textObject.y > HEIGHT) return;
    if (textObject.x < 0 || textObject.y < 0) return;

    context.fillStyle = textObject.fillColor;
    context.font = textObject.fontWeight + " " + textObject.fontSize + " " + textObject.fontFamily;

    context.fillText(textObject.text, textObject.x, textObject.y);
}
// Happens when the mouse is moving inside the canvas
function myMove(e) {
    if (isDrag) {
        getMouse(e);

        mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
        mySel.y = my - offsety;

        // something is changing position so we better invalidate the canvas!
        invalidate();
    }
}
function myDown(e) {
    getMouse(e);
    clear(gctx);
    var lText = textObjects.length;
    for (var i = lText - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // draw shape onto ghost context
        drawText(gctx, textObjects[i]);

        // get image data at the mouse x,y pixel
        var imageData = gctx.getImageData(mx, my, 1, 1);
        var index = (mx + my * imageData.width) * 4;

        // if the mouse pixel exists, select and break
        if (imageData.data[3] > 0) {
            mySel = textObjects[i];
            offsetx = mx - mySel.x;
            offsety = my - mySel.y;
            mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
            mySel.y = my - offsety;
            isDrag = true;
            canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
            invalidate();
            clear(gctx);
            alertSelected();
            return;
        }

    }
    // havent returned means we have selected nothing
    mySel = null;
    // clear the ghost canvas for next time
    clear(gctx);
    // invalidate because we might need the selection border to disappear
    invalidate();
}
function invalidate() {
    canvasValid = false;
}
function getMouse(e) {
    var element = canvas, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;

    if (element.offsetParent) {
        do {
            offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
            offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
    }

    // Add padding and border style widths to offset
    offsetX += stylePaddingLeft;
    offsetY += stylePaddingTop;

    offsetX += styleBorderLeft;
    offsetY += styleBorderTop;

    mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
    my = e.pageY - offsetY
}
$("#btn-bold").click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < textObjects.length() ; i++) {
        if ((textObjects[i].x == mySel.x) && (textObjects[i].y == mySel.y)) {
            if (textObjects[i].fontWeight == "normal") {
                textObjects[i].fontWeight = "bold";
            }
            if (textObjects[i].fontWeight == "bold") {
                textObjects[i].fontWeight = "normal";
            }
        }
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="top-level">
    <div class="row" id="content-header">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Edit Photo's EditorView.cshtml</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="content-middle">
        <div id="designer-canvas" class="col-md-8">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("ClientPage"); }
        </div>
        <div id="content-builder" class="col-md-4">
            <row>
                <div id=text-input-top-level class="col-md-12">
                    <h3><label>Text</label></h3>
                    <textarea id="text-inputarea" , placeholder="Text here."></textarea>
                </div>
            </row>
            <hr />
            <row>
                <div id="text-size-check" class="col-md-12">
                    <h4>Font Size</h4>
                    <div id="font-size-slider">
                        <div id="font-size-slider-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </row>
            <hr />
            <row>
                <div id="text-weight-check" class="col-md-6">
                    <h4>Font Weight</h4>
                    <div id="text-weight-check-buttons">
                        <button id="btn-bold">B</button>
                        <button id="btn-italic">I</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="text-position" class="col-md-6">
                    <h4>Text Position</h4>
                    <div id="text-position-buttons">
                        <button>1</button>
                        <button>2</button>
                        <button>3</button>
                        <button>4</button>
                        <button>5</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </row>
            <hr />
            <row>

            </row>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ClientPage.cshtml**

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Nobody ever calls `addText`, at least not in what you posted.

Comment: Can you make it into a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Are you sure mySel is undefined, and not just null,.. Because in myDown you set it to null.  if on your button click, you just do console.log(mySel), and console.log(textObjects), what do you get?

Comment: Please scale this down to a [mcve] and remove all code not relevant to the specific problem

Comment: @TimSeguine My post explains that I call `addText` in the JQuery modal button. @Keith It's only set to null if no object from the canvas was hit. The variable is never null as it only gets set in the myDown method. @JNF I'm having trouble getting the code to work in jsfiddle. Prehaps now the code is more readeable. https://jsfiddle.net/7paqrm22/1/

Comment: @DaBazz Yeah, the point was, this needs to be a minimal, complete, verifiable example. The code you posted clearly doesn't work for the reason I mentioned. Is that the only reason? I dunno, but if you can't be bothered to make a minimal, complete, verifiable example I can't be bothered to check.

Comment: Solved the issue by calling my function from a HTML button, which I added on the EditorView, instead of trying to call it from the JQUery Modal Button.